# Mysql JOIN syntax error getting specified columns data

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, join

I have 2 tables, one is `setting` and one is `accounts`

`setting` has columns of: isVerified, customMessage, user
`accounts` has columns of: id, fullName, password, address, phone

I know I have to do `join` but how do I get only `fullName` from accounts table?

I did this

```
SELECT isVerified, customMessage, fullName
FROM setting FULL OUTER JOIN
     accounts
     ON setting.user = accounts.id;
```

but got error near the `JOIN`. What's wrong?

Comment: MySQL does not support full outer join (but there are workarounds).  Can you add some sample data which helps to explain what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An inner join should suffice:

```
SELECT s.isVerified, s.customMessage, a.fullName
FROM setting s INNER JOIN
     accounts a 
     ON s.user = a.id;
```

MySQL does not support `FULL OUTER JOIN`.  Presumably, all accounts have settings and vice versa.

Note that I introduced table aliases so the query is easier to write and to read.  And, in this query, all column names specify the table they come from.

Comment: are you missing `setting as s`?

Comment: @Melissa93 . . . No.  `as` is not required for table aliases, and I don't like using `as` in that context.

Answer (score 0):

> I know I have to do join but how do I get only fullName from accounts
>   table?

If you only want fullName only specify fullName column in your select statement.

> Select fullname FROM ....

As others have pointed out MySQL doesn't support FULL OUTER JOIN so change that to simply JOIN as Gordon Linoff has mentioned above.

Normally when you do a join you either want rows that match both the tables (setting and accounts in your case). Based on the columns you've described and depending on how you've designed your schema it's either a One to One relationship between two tables or One to Many. Your case sounds like one to one as each users account will have a setting.

You're joining on s.user = a.id but I don't see you mentioned s.user is actually same as a.id? What is the user field? Perhaps you need  to name this better as s.id if it's actually an id. As others have pointed out please include your actual table definition so it's easier to figure out why you get the SQL error while running your query.

Good luck.

Comment: thanks for the explanation, the error come from FULL OUTER JOIN.